# VBScript - Syntax Error in FROM Clause

Tags: sql, vbscript

So I'd just like to preface this by saying I have very little experience with VBS. But anyway, I'm trying to write this script where I want to calculate the year number of a project (but leave it blank under certain circumstances) from a database storing several projects.

There error I'm receiving is:
Error 800A0C3B – Syntax error in From clause.
Line 26
Char 1
Source: DAO.Database
and I can't quite figure out how to fix it.

```
Option Explicit 'Line 1
'Declare Variables
Dim rs1
Dim rs2
Dim Year '5
Dim YearNo
Dim oAccess
Dim oShell
Dim dbLocation
Dim currentdb '10
Dim sql
Dim Program_Year
Dim Construction_Year
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("scripting.fileSystemObject") '15
Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

dbLocation = "[drive]\folder\folder\file.accdb"

Set oAccess = createobject("Access.Application") '20

oAccess.opencurrentdatabase(dbLocation)

'sql = "SELECT * FROM [Expenditures] IN '" & dbLocation & "' "
'25
oAccess.currentdb.execute("SELECT * FROM [Expenditures] IN '" & dbLocation & "'""") '26

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(oAccess)

'Move to first record '30
rs1.MoveFirst
'Copy recordset
Set rs2 = rs1.Clone
rs2.Bookmark = rs1.Bookmark
rs2.MoveNext '35

Do While Not rs2.EOF

            rs2.Edit

'1. Check if Construction Year is before Program Year '40
If Me.Construction_Year < Me.Program_Year Then

'a) If year comes before program year, leave yearno blank
 If Me.Year < Me.Program_Year Then
     Me.YearNo = "" '45
 'b) If year is program year or is greater than program year, fill in yearno
 ElseIf Me.Year > Me.Program_Year or Me.Year = Me.Program_Year Then
     If rs1.Year < rs2.Year And Trim(rs1.GWP) = Trim(rs2.GWP) Then
         rs2.YearNo = rs2.Year - rs1.Year + rs1.YearNo
     End If '50
 End If

'2. Check if Program Year is Before Construction Year
ElseIf Me.Program_Year < Me.Construction_Year Then
'55
 'a) If year comes before construction year, leave yearno blank
 If Me.Year < Me.Construction_Year Then
     Me.YearNo =""
 'b) If year is construction year or is greater than construction year, fill in yearno
 ElseIf Me.Year > Me.Construction_Year or Me.Year = Me.Construction_Year Then '60
     If rs1.Year < rs2.Year And Trim(rs1.GWP) = Trim(rs2.GWP) Then
         rs2.YearNo = rs2.Year - rs1.Year + rs1.YearNo
     End If
 End If
'3. Check if Program Year and Construction Year are the same '65
ElseIf Me.ProgramYear = Me.Construction_Year Then
 'a) If year comes before program year, leave yearno blank
 If Me.Year < Me.Program_Year Then
     Me.YearNo = ""
 'b) Otherwise fill in yearno '70
 ElseIf rs1.Year < rs2.Year And Trim(rs1.GWP) = Trim(rs2.GWP) Then
         rs2.YearNo = rs2.Year - rs1.Year + rs1.YearNo
     End If
 End If
'80
'End If

'Update and move to next

            rs2.Update

rs1.MoveNext '85

            rs2.MoveNext

        Loop


        'Close recordsets and set to nothing

rs2.Close '90

        rs1.Close

        Set rs1 = Nothing

        Set rs2 = Nothing

'95
oShell.Popup "Update Complete!",2, "",0

oAccess.quit
Set oAccess = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Any assistance - with this and any obvious problems in my code - would be most gratefully appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot to add that the database is based in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL? looks like access. this is code from a really old VBScript. may help:

```vb
' CursorTypeEnum Values
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Const adOpenDynamic = 2
Const adOpenStatic = 3

' LockTypeEnum Values
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Const adLockPessimistic = 2
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4

' CommandTypeEnum Values
Const adCmdUnknown = &H0008
Const adCmdText = &H0001
Const adCmdTable = &H0002
Const adCmdStoredProc = &H0004

Dim Connection, rs, item, svcOpsRA(1), datafile, n, fs
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim CurrentPath, CurrentFolder
set CurrentPath = fs.GetFolder(".")
CurrentFolder = CurrentPath.path
set CurrentPath = nothing

Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 30
Connection.CommandTimeout = 80
datafile = CurrentFolder & "\deploy.mdb"
Connection.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" & datafile & ";DefaultDir=;UID=;PWD=;"
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

rs.Open "SELECT Service, State FROM svcOps WHERE Status", Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
while not rs.EOF
    n = 0
    for each item in rs.Fields
        svcOpsRA(n) = item.value ' ... populating an array with the values
        n = n + 1
    next
    svcOps svcOpsRA(0), svcOpsRA(1) ' ... basically call a sub/function and pass 2 fields as parameters
    rs.MoveNext
wend
rs.Close

Connection.Close
set rs = nothing
set Connection = nothing
set fs = nothing
```

the `svcOps` sub looks something like:

```vb
sub svcOps(service,state) ' ... takes 2 parameters
    ' ... do something
end sub
```

also, if you plan to update the recordset, use `adOpenDynamic` instead of `adOpenForwardOnly` ;)

here's the documentation on the record lock and enum types: [MSDN - Recordset Object Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141422%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: You should add some commentary, to explain why your code is a solution.

Comment: @AndyG hmm, ok adding some commentary: because it's the correct way of doing things (besides the fact that i'm calling `svcOps` sub in the `rs` loop ;p that should be in a separate for-each after the recordset is closed. also allows you to control record locking behaviour if the database is in use by another party/application.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM [Expenditures] IN '" & dbLocation & "'"""
```

This is invalid syntax. If you want to use IN then it could be:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Expenditures] WHERE somefield IN('val1','val2','val3')"
```

If the values are variables then you still need to insert them using concatenation &.

```
"SELECT * FROM [Expenditures] WHERE somefield IN('" & val1 & "','" & val_etc & "')"
```

Or,

```
"SELECT * FROM [Expenditures] WHERE somefield = 'val1'"
```

If `val1` is a number then you don't need apostrophes.

Comment: you can just create a connection though, with proper locks. no need to open the access application object.

Comment: @porkchop Quite right. But, to me, that belongs as a comment and suggestion on the OP's code, rather than as an answer to their question and error message.

Comment: So I changed 'sql = "SELECT * FROM [Expenditures] WHERE somefield = val1"

'WHERE GWP = '" + Me.GWP + "' ORDER BY Year"

'oAccess.currentdb.execute("SELECT * FROM [Expenditures]") '25

 

'Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("sql") to Set rs1 = CurrentDb.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

      strQuery = "select * from Expenditures" '30

 
      Set rs1 = oConnection.Execute("strQuery"), and now I'm getting  Line 29
Char 1
800A01A8  - Object Required: “
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error. Any suggestions?